# trying to add images to scroll view

Tags: java, android, xml, image, scrollview

I am trying to add multiple images to vertical scroll view in android.

It works fine with one image but If I put 2 images,

```
 02-19 19:56:29.992: E/AndroidRuntime(5036): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-19 19:56:29.992: E/AndroidRuntime(5036): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.con4/com.example.con4.Options}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #86: Error inflating class <unknown>
02-19 19:56:29.992: E/AndroidRuntime(5036):
```

I am not too sure what the problem is.  I have also tried using different images to try. I think there is an issue with my xml

The xml is the following

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".Options" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2" >

    <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/lin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/help" 
            android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/helpa"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
            />



    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: could you post full xml

Comment: ScrollView says android:layout_below="@+id/textView2". where is textView2 in your layout?

Comment: copy paste, there was more to my xml, but thought it is not necessary to post

Comment: your layout work fine with me i , add three images

Comment: could you post Activtiy code

Comment: there is no ref to it in my activity code

Comment: @dhali what do you mean with no ref ? where the Activity that make the problem so ?

Comment: No as its only images in scroll view i dont have any java code ref them specifically

Comment: but i can still post it

Comment: I just thought it was an issue with xml

Comment: it's best approach  if you find the solution post it as answer